# How can I add different Markers in an XY Scatter Graph in Excel using value from a different column?

Tags: excel, scatter

I have the following Dataset where my Date is my X-Axis. I would like to plot a Scatter Graph in Excel where Y-Value = 1 against the Date but I would like different Markers for my Groups. I don't however want to print the Group.

```
A = Circle
B = Diamond
C = Square
D = Triangle

Date         Y-Value   Group
01-JAN-2020    1         A
01-FEB-2020    1         A
01-MAR-2020    1         B
01-APR-2020
01-MAY-2020    1         C
01-JUN-2020
01-JUL-2020
01-AUG-2020    1         D
01-SEP-2020    1         A
01-OCT-2020
01-NOV-2020
01-DEC-2020    1         C
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to set up a different series for each group.

Set up the data like below in columns A to E, then insert the scatter plot:

[image]

Then in chart, right click on a data point from each group and select Format Data Series to change the shape of the points for that group:

[image]

On the panel on the right, you'll have to select

1. Fill & Line
2. Marker
3. Marker Options
4. Built-In
5. Type
6. Then select the type you want

[image]

While you're there, increasing the marker Size might make it easier to see the different shapes:

[image]